# Shared variables not working when create a new class instance

Tags: vb.net, shared-variable, object-class

I have a class (ServerASync) with a shared Hashtable variable `bSocket_Monitored`.
The variable values of `bSocket_Monitored` are shared between instances in different way in respect to how I declare the instances.

In the main form, if I declare the class instances as:

```
private withevents P1 as new ServerASync
private withevents P2 as new ServerASync
private withevents P3 as new ServerASync
```

etc..
all of them share the same `bSocket_Monitored`.

But if declare a new instance as:

```
private withevents P4 as ServerASync
```

and then

```
P4 = new ServerASync
```

the `bSocket_Monitored` is reset and lost all the previous values.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: How is the `bSocket_Monitored` variable declared? And what is in your constructor of the `ServerASync` class. Don't you clear the hashtable in the constructor by chance?

Comment: What you describe is not default behaviour, so it's definitely something you're doing. I concur with Peter that you are almost certainly creating a hew `Hashtable` in the constructor. That would make sense for an instance field but not a `Shared` field. You should either create a new `Hashtable` where the field is declared or in a `Shared` constructor but nowhere else.

Comment: The variable bbSocket_Monitored  is defined in the class:
Private bbSocket_Monitored As Hashtable

In the class constructor (New):
bbSocket_Monitored = New Hashtable

Comment: What does "shared between instances in different way in respect to how I declare the instances" mean? That's not at all clear as to what you're doing.

Comment: Your `Private bbSocket_Monitored As Hashtable` is not shared, there's no `Shared` keyword. So each instance of the `ServerASync` class has its own hashtable instance. According to this, P1, P2 and P3 should NOT share the same `bSocket_Monitored` as you wrote. Moreover, even if the variable was `Shared`, you re-create the hashtable each time in the constructor. So once you create P4, the variable is set to an empty hashtable and the previous hashtable is lost for good. All P1-P4 would share the same empty hashtable.